# system.text.json search a dynamic json

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I have this JSON string:

```
string jsonString =
  "{
    "users":[
      {"name":"John", "code":"white", "job":"actor"},
      {"name":"Oliver", "code":"black", "job": "seller"}
     ]
  }"
```

then deserialize it using:

```
JsonElement je = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString).RootElement;
JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator users = je.GetProperty("users").EnumerateArray();
```

with system.text.json how can I get first JsonElement whose code is "black"?
I mean without loops (foreach, ...).

with newtonsoft.json I could simply do this:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
dynamic user = json.SelectToken("[?(@.code == 'black')]");
string name = user["name"], job = user["job"];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how can I get first JsonElement whose code is "black"

I would create classes that represent your `json` structure and then deserialize to those classes.

You can create your classes as such:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class People
{   
    [JsonPropertyName("users")]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{   
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("job")]
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize:

```
string jsonString = "{\"users\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"code\":\"white\",\"job\":\"actor\"},{\"name\":\"Oliver\",\"code\":\"black\",\"job\":\"seller\"}]}";
People people = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<People>(jsonString);
```

Now you can get the first `User` object where `code` is black:

```
 var usr = people.Users.Where(u => u.Code == "black").FirstOrDefault();
```

[Here's the](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNIP5l) example you can run.

**UPDATE PER COMMENT**

> it is dynamic JSON

You can deserialize your `json` to `JsonElement` and then try and get the properties you want.

```
var people = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString);
if(people is JsonElement je && je.TryGetProperty("users", out je)){ 
   // obj will be JsonElement if match is found
   var obj = je.EnumerateArray().Where(je => je.TryGetProperty("code", out je) && je.GetString() == "black").FirstOrDefault();  
   // Get what you need
   var name = obj.TryGetProperty("name", out JsonElement eleName) ? eleName.GetString() : "No name";
   var job = obj.TryGetProperty("job", out JsonElement eleJob) ? eleJob.GetString() : "No job";
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\n{1}", name, job));
}
```

*You can [test this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0lLg2) code there

Comment: No, it's not my option. As I said in title, it is dynamic JSON.